# Why does my keras custom layer fit well on training data but gives bad results on validation?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to understand how Keras custom layers works, but I am facing a problem with the validation accuracy of my model.

I tried to reproduce a simple convolutional network on MNIST dataset but with a custom layer combining the Conv2D operator and the BatchNormalisation.

**First, the data I used :**

```py
from keras.datasets import mnist
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
X_train = np.array([x.reshape(28, 28, 1) for x in X_train])
X_test = np.array([x.reshape(28, 28, 1) for x in X_test])
y_train = pd.get_dummies(y_train)
y_test = pd.get_dummies(y_test)
```

**Here is the original implementation which works well :**

```py
def get_model():
    input_ = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
    x = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", input_shape=(28,28,1))(input_)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(input_)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(input_)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(128, activation="relu")(x)
    x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(x)
    x = Dense(10, activation="softmax")(x)
    mod = Model(inputs=input_, outputs=x)
    return mod

optim = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, clipvalue=K.epsilon())
model = get_model()
model.compile(optimizer=optim, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=3, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

With this initial model, after 3 epochs, I get a train accuracy of 97% and validation 97%

**And here is my custom layer :**

```py
class Conv2DLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, dropout_ratio=None, strides=(1, 1), activation="relu", use_bn=True, *args, **kwargs):
        self._filters = filters
        self._kernel_size = kernel_size
        self._dropout_ratio = dropout_ratio
        self._strides = strides
        self.use_bn = use_bn
        self._activation = activation
        self._args = args
        self._kwargs = kwargs
        super(Conv2DLayer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):

        self.conv = Conv2D(self._filters,
                           kernel_size=self._kernel_size,
                           activation=self._activation,
                           strides=self._strides,
                           input_shape=input_shape,
                           *self._args,
                           **self._kwargs)
        self.conv.build(input_shape)
        self.out_conv_shape = self.conv.compute_output_shape(input_shape)
        self._trainable_weights = self.conv._trainable_weights
        self._non_trainable_weights = self.conv._non_trainable_weights

        if self.use_bn:
            self.bn = BatchNormalization()
            self.bn.build(self.out_conv_shape)
            self._trainable_weights.extend(self.bn._trainable_weights)
            self._non_trainable_weights.extend(self.bn._non_trainable_weights)

        if self._dropout_ratio is not None:
            self.dropout = Dropout(rate=self._dropout_ratio)
            self.dropout.build(self.out_conv_shape)
            self._trainable_weights.extend(self.dropout._trainable_weights)
            self._non_trainable_weights.extend(self.dropout._non_trainable_weights)

        super(Conv2DLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.conv(inputs)
        if self.use_bn:
            x = self.bn(x)
        if self._dropout_ratio is not None:
            x = self.dropout(x)
        return x

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return self.out_conv_shape
```

**Finally, here is the modified model :**

```py
def get_model():
    input_ = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
    x = Conv2DLayer(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(input_)
    x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
    x = Conv2DLayer(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(input_)
    x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
    x = Conv2DLayer(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(input_)
    x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(128, activation="relu")(x)
    x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(x)
    x = Dense(10, activation="softmax")(x)
    mod = Model(inputs=input_, outputs=x)
    return mod
```

For this model with custom layer, I managed to get the same train accuracy (97%), but the validation accuracy get stuck around 50%.

## EDIT

Thanks to Matias Valdenegro, I achieved to solve the problem by modifying the `call` method :

```py
def call(self, inputs):
    training = K.learning_phase()
    x = self.conv(inputs)
    if self.use_bn:
        x = self.bn(x, training=training)
    if self._dropout_ratio is not None:
        x = self.dropout(x, training=training)
    return x
```

With `K` the `keras.backend` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Dropout and Batch Normalization behave differently during training and testing/inference, and your layer does not have any of that behavior, so its using  those inner layers as training mode during inference, producing incorrect results.

I am not sure but I think you can fix this by passing the `training` parameter in the `call` function call through the layers, something like:

```
def call(self, inputs, training=None):
    x = self.conv(inputs)
    if self.use_bn:
        x = self.bn(x, training=training)
    if self._dropout_ratio is not None:
        x = self.dropout(x, training=training)
    return x
```

This should make the inner layers work differently during train and testing/inference phases.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't know why but the parameter `training=None` doesn't seem to work, so I used the function `keras.backend.learning_phase()` to get the training variable and now it works !

Comment: @RVaysse That is odd, you should not need to set learning phase manually, maybe there is another issue.